# How can i change Facebook PixelID without reloading a Single Page Application?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am working for an international ecommerce project which is operation on different countries. Each country is independent from each other.

I have a Single Page Applicatioin (SPA/Angular) with different tracking pixels for each country e.g. AT (Austria), DE(Germany), BE (belgium), DK (denmark) and only one domain e.g. www.example.co.uk. Each country want to track their own data. Sending DE data to BE is not allowed! (addPixelId is not a solution)

Users are able to change country by using a combobox.I need to change the pixel ID for selected country. It is possible with google pixel but I havenot seen any documentation on the about faceboook pixel.

I asked the same question for [Google Analytics TrackingID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543181/change-google-analytics-trackingid-after-creating-it) and found a solution for it. But I currently could not find a solution for Facebook PixelID yet.

How can i change Facebook Pixel ID without reloading the Single Page Application?

Screenshot of application mockup:
[image]

Comment: Hi . Are you using a Tag manager tool in your project(like google tag manager or Adobe tag manager)? Basically, if you are using a tag manager, you can create a list if country and pixel id, and control the load pixel, based  on country domain site.

Answer (score 0):

Technically there isn't an officially supported way to do this.

You *could* look at how the FB pixel works, which is to define methods called `fbq` and `_fbq` on the `window`, redefine these as `null` and then re-call the pixel code with the new pixel ID.

This would probably work, but I'm not sure if there will be any side effects.

Assuming you first have initialised the pixel using something like this:

```
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'PIXEL_ID_1'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
fbq('track', 'PageView');
```

Now you need to change the pixel ID. The pixel IDs are stored in a function scoped variable within the `fbq` method defined by the above pixel code.

So you'll need to redefine this method remove the pixel ID.

```
window.fbq = window._fbq = null;
```

You can then re-call the entire pixel code, with the new ID:

```
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'PIXEL_ID_2'); // Insert your 2nd pixel ID here.
fbq('track', 'PageView');
```

You should us the Facebook Pixel Helper for Chrome to debug this.

Comment: It is not possible to remove an implementation from the browser memory once it is executed!.

Comment: what do you mean?! You can redefine methods whenever you want and the IDs of the pixels are stored in these methods as they're function scoped.

Comment: @KorayGüclü - I think you answered your own question, you have to deallocated the memory first, which is why I was saying to re-define fbq. See updated description.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but your suggested solution donot work. It is not possible to null a function implementation once it has been started to listen DOM Events. The reference that you are nullfying will not have any effect on implementation because it is already loaded into browser memory and working from there.Nullfying and reinitating the FB will therefore have no affect.